# multi dimensional array objects

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to access elements in a multi dimensional array using JS. this doesn't seem to work. pls help

```
var parsed = "";
 var myObject = [{
     firstname: "Jane",
     lastname: "Doe",
     email: "jdoe@email.com"
 }, {
     firstname: "Ja",
     lastname: "joe",
     email: "je@email.com"
 }];
 for (var prop in myObject) {
     parsed += prop + ": " + myObject[prop] + "\n";
 }
 alert(parsed);
```

Comment: what error are you getting with this code?

Comment: depends what you want, but to get some meaningful output ( based on your input ) you should be accessing `myObject[prop].firstname/lastname/email` etc.

Comment: if its just a one dimensional array..i get the correct response. This code throws up the following: 0[object Object] 1[object Object]

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate array and select proper property by name:

```
var parsed = "";
var myObject = [{
     firstname: "Jane",
     lastname: "Doe",
     email: "jdoe@email.com"
  },
  {
     firstname: "Ja",
     lastname: "joe",
     email: "je@email.com"
  },
];
for(var item in myObject)
{
  for (var prop in item) {
    parsed += prop + ": " + item[prop] + "\n";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need an other loop to iterate over array element.

```
var parsed = "";
var myObject = [{
     firstname: "Jane",
     lastname: "Doe",
     email: "jdoe@email.com"
},
 {
     firstname: "Ja",
     lastname: "joe",
     email: "je@email.com"
 },
 ];
for (i = 0; i< myObject.length; i++){
    var myobj=  myObject[i];
  for (var prop in myobj) {
     parsed += prop + ": " + myobj[prop] + "\n";
 }
}
 alert(parsed);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7rdo68wz/)**

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code snippets for you.
Your basic mistake is that `myObject` is an array of objects so you have to loop over the array and then over the object in the given index

```
var attr,
        prop,
        parsed = "",
        myObject = [
            {
                firstname: "Jane",
                lastname: "Doe",
                email: "jdoe@email.com"
            },
            {
                firstname: "Ja",
                lastname: "joe",
                email: "je@email.com"
            }
        ];


// My object is an array
myObject.forEach(function(item, index, array) {

    // Verify to see that the property you want is yours and not inherited
    for (attr in item) {
        if (item.hasOwnProperty(attr)) {
            parsed += attr + ": " + item[attr] + "\n";
        }
    }

})

alert(parsed);
```